# Finding the "Airport Express Shuttle Bus" at Hong Kong station?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, hong-kong, hkg

In a few days time, I fly into Hong Kong International Airport (HKG). Having read through the [WikiVoyage section on getting from the airport](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong#By_plane), I'm planning to take the Airport Express.

The directions section of my hotel's website says:

> take Airport Express to Hong Kong station and interchange the Airport Express Shuttle-bus (H1, to Western District), it is a complimentary add-on service provided exclusively for Airport Express passengers travelling between Hong Kong station and our hotel

This seems like quite a convenient option for me, since I won't have to try to navigate to the hotel with a load of bags when jetlagged.

However... I can't seem to find anything about these shuttle buses, specifically where I'll need to go when I reach Hong Kong station to find them, and how well sign posted they are?

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions but one thing I remember is that everything is extremely well sign-posted and organized in Hong Kong. Navigating the public transport network for example was easier than in most places I know in Europe. The only thing that confused me a little are the taxis.

Comment: @Annoyed you are right. The only thing with REALLY bad sign-posts are the streets in case you have to drive yourself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you arrive with the airport express you will be in an underground station 2 floors below the IFC Mall. There will be two exits: The one on the same level to a taxi station. The other one will be an escalator leading up to the airport express check-in on ground level. Go up the escalator 2 floors. There will be the check-in counter on one side of the hall and a long window with exits and cars passing by on the other side of the hall. Go out through the doors outside and the [airport express buses](http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/getting_around/complom_free_bus.html) will stop right in front of you, [rather to the left side of the building](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m8!1m3!1d3!2d114.157952!3d22.28504!2m2!1f208.21!2f87.34!4f75!2m7!1e1!2m2!1sE_JelcZLO9EVZWZo57edGQ!2e0!5m2!1sE_JelcZLO9EVZWZo57edGQ!2e0&fid=5). The right side is blocked with cars dropping off passengers.

Since the buses are coming only every 20 minutes, and since your taxi will cost less than 50 HKD, you might want to just take one on the same level when you leave the train. Depending on the amount of people on the train, you could face a 10 minute wait for a taxi also, but you will be able to judge that right when you leave the train before you go up 2 floors to the bus station.

Comment: Also, in case you're concerned OP, the buses also have recorded announcements and info screens for each stop in Cantonese, Mandarin and English so you shouldn't miss your stop. Lastly, all MTR and Airport Express (operated by the MTR) stations are manned, and as you're entering at a very busy and tourist-focused station, you'll have no issues finding someone that speaks enough English to help you out if you get lost (MTR staff have yellow tops on with the MTR logo IIRC).

Answer (score 5):

I've done this. There are clear signs at the station, as soon as you get off the train, directing you towards the shuttle buses. Just look for and follow the signs.